# Flash date and time and coutdown timer

Tags: flash

does any one know of any good countdown timer's for flash which i can use to be implemented in a flash game or quiz ?

also i have the following line of code

```
var endDate:Date = new Date(2010,7,30);
```

how would i go about having the endDate to be the current time and date + 30 minutes ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is to add 30 minutes to the current time

```
var min:Number = 30;
var mSecs:Number = min * 60 * 1000;
var sum:Number = mSecs + date.getTime();

var newTime:Date = new Date(sum);
```